# "Send As" using Gmail for Work

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, send, google-workspace

I have two different gmail accounts: one normal (free version), one gmail for Work. I only use the browser client of gmail (free version) to check my emails from about 10 different accounts. I therefore also configured this account to send emails using other email addresses. It all works fine.

The issue comes when I try to configure this account to send as a Gmail for Work address. As for Gmail for Work addresses, the domain name is different than "@gmail.com", it seems that the gmail browser client does not recognize it as a gmail address. It then asks me for smtp and other mail parameters, but returns me this error:

---

Authentication failed. Please check your username/password.
[Server response: DNS Error: 15357910 DNS type 'aaaa' lookup of smtp.mydomain.ch responded with code NXDOMAIN 15357910 DNS type 'a' lookup of smtp.mydomain.ch responded with code NXDOMAIN code(0) ]

---

I set:
SMTP servers: smtp.mydomain.ch
username: lr@mydomain.ch
password: mypassword
And tried with TLS or SSL and changing the port.

Any idea what could I do?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the basic setup for Gmail for Work, the Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server settings are the same as the ones that use the Gmail (free/for consumers / gmail.com) accounts.

From [Read Gmail messages on other email clients using IMAP](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en)

```
Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server  |  smtp.gmail.com 
                             |  Requires TLS: Yes (if available)  
                             |  Requires Authentication: Yes   
                             |  Port for SSL: 465  
                             |  Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587
```

Another help article about SMTP settings: [G Suite SMTP settings to send mail from a printer, scanner, or app](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)